# Why onDataChange() is never called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is simple method for reading long value from one child in my database.

The same method also gives me null for pojo.

What am I doing wrong ???
Why OnDataChanged() is skipped?

(Path to child : UserData/DeviceMgmt/Average:)

here is the code:

```
public class DevicesUtil {
public final static FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
public final static DatabaseReference dbRefUserData = firebaseDatabase.getReference("UserData");
public final static DatabaseReference dbRefUsers = dbRefUserData.child("Users");
public final static DatabaseReference dbRefDisplayNames = dbRefUserData.child("DisplayNames");
public final static DatabaseReference dbRefDeviceMgmt = dbRefUserData.child("DeviceMgmt");
public final static DatabaseReference dbRefAverage = dbRefDeviceMgmt.child("Average");
public final static DatabaseReference dbRefDevices = dbRefDeviceMgmt.child("Devices");
public final static DatabaseReference dbRefNumberOfAll = dbRefDeviceMgmt.child("NumberOfAll");
public final static DatabaseReference dbRefNumberOfSelected = dbRefDeviceMgmt.child("NumberOfSelected");
public final static DatabaseReference dbRefTotalDownloaded = dbRefDeviceMgmt.child("TotalDownloaded");

    private static long theAverage;

    public static long getAverage() {
        dbRefAverage.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                theAverage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, databaseError.getMessage() + ", Exception: ", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
        return theAverage;
    }

public static User getDbUser(final String uid) {
    // getting User value:
    dbRefUsers.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userValue = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, databaseError.getMessage() + ", Exception: ", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });

}}
```

and Json:

```
{
```

"UserData" : {
    "DeviceMgmt" : {
      "Average" : 666,
      "Devices" : {
        "-LEPhxstDLC-SJKITtCI" : {
          "downloaded" : 0,
          "failures" : 0,
          "fcmToken" : "dRneV",
          "signOutTime" : 0,
          "toSelect" : true,
          "uid" : "AsU7GKtuTSZFwm3ePwvk4s3AEbT2",
          "used" : 0
        },
        "Device" : "dummy"
      },
      "NumberOfAll" : 8,
      "NumberOfSelected" : 8,
      "TotalDownloaded" : 0
    },
    "DisplayNames" : {
      "Pablo X" : "tWlLHuDgGVPr0ZivEEpIi4tik352",
      "Pablo XY" : "0HW3pcWHU9YuPYM4Od4YBqDzB8C3",
      "Pawel" : "AsU7GKtuTSZFwm3ePwvk4s3AEbT2",
      "displayName" : "dummy"
    },
    "Users" : {
      "AsU7GKtuTSZFwm3ePwvk4s3AEbT2" : {
        "deviceKey" : "-LEPhxstDLC-SJKITtCI",
        "displayName" : "Pawel",
        "email" : "email@gmail.com",
        "profile" : "user",
        "signOutTime" : 0
      },
      "user" : "dummy"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Can you add the JSON at the location that you query (as text, no screenshot please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: And: is your `onDataChange` being called at all?

Comment: And console show some error?

Comment: onDataChange() is not called. That's a problem

Comment: You can't `return theAverage` from `getAverage()` because `onDataChange()` fires asynchronously.  The method completes before `onDataChange()` runs.  Perhaps that is making it appear that `onDataChange()` is not called.

Comment: So, how can I return that value from onDataChange ?
I thought global variable was a good idea...
As I understand the only way to get firebase child value is adding ValueEventListener with this callback...

Comment: Ok. I spent 2 days on that. If anyone have an idea how to synchronise it... Europeans go to sleep...thx

Comment: You cannot return something now that hasn't been loaded yet. Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.